# Enviar datos al controlador en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Definí un valor por defecto en un formulario que tengo en una vista (`@Value="afar1793"`) y lo coloque `disabled` para que no pudiese ser modificado pero al llegar al controlador se hace `null`.

Tengo esto en mi código:

**Vista:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_Usuario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id_Usuario, Usuario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value ="afar1793", @disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_Usuario, "", new {@class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Registrar(Usuarios usu)
{
//Codigo
}
```

Comment: No sería mejor asignarle el valor en el controlador? y en la caja de texto sólo muestras un *placeholder* con la cadena por defecto...

Comment: Seria bueno conocer cual es la idea de porque lo colocas como disabled a un elemento que quieres que vaya en el response del formulario, cual es la funcionalidad o requerimiento final

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas un elemento de formulario (un elemento submiteable) y seteas el atributo disabled esto hace que en la mayoría de los navegadores modernos no se envie al realizar el submit del form.
Puedes ver mas info en [W3C > Html4.1 > Forms > disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled)

Es decir es un comportamiento "normal" de formularios HTTP con los elementos disabled

Ahora bien, si la idea es visualizar un elemento para no modificarlo al usuario pero enviarlo: Debes prevenir que no se pueda modificar en ningún momento. O sea renderizarlo en el form, pero con un texto simplemente 
(imaginate si el usuario podría modificarlo en el submit, que lo puede hacer mas allá que este disabled o no, o enviártelo en un request)
Si es un valor o texto que debe ser visible, puedes colocarlo pero en el controlador ya seteado, y en el response (volverlo a generar). Claro, depende de como se debe generar este valor

Tambien esta la posibilidad de utilizar post por javascript (ajax), por ejemplo un controlador angular que haga el response por algun service/factory, o algun otro metodo... pero siempre peticiones http por javascript... y aqui puedes obtener los valores de "donde desees" (incluso elementos deshabilitados) y alli es otra historia

Pero si la idea es simple de botones submit que haga post del formulario, los elementos disabled no se enviaran.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía....